# Why are my Tag Manager triggers never firing when I set the condition to "matches CSS condition"?

Tags: google-analytics, css, google-tag-manager

In Tag Manager, I set up a Link Click trigger with these conditions:

**Click Classes** > **matches CSS selector** > **.amazon-button**

But for some reason, when I click on an Amazon button, the trigger never fires.

My other tags work fine, so everything should be set up correctly. What could be causing this issue?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the first value (the variable) to **Click Element** rather than Click Classes.

[image]

I'm not sure why they designed it like that. It seems pretty unintuitive.